# Show custom dialog when spinner is being clicked

Tags: android

Currently, I have the spinner in `dialog` mode.

```
        <Spinner
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            android:id="@+id/genderSpinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:entries="@array/gender_array"
            android:prompt="@string/gender_prompt" />
```

It will show something like this

[image]

However, sometimes, I will like to have control on what type of dialog to be shown. For instance, I will like to show a dialog with a date picker when the spinner is clicked.

Note, Google Calendar does have such controls.

[image]

May I know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Do not use Spinner, but using TextView, and install a click listener to it.

In order to turn TextView looks like Spinner, here is the technique

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.72"
            android:text="Aug 20, 2012"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner" />
```

or

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.72"
            android:text="Aug 20, 2012"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner" />
```

Comment: Better to use `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have trouble making that work with a Spinner. The concept of a Spinner is such that it is expecting to show a list of items for the user to choose from.

Instead of a Spinner I think you should use a Button that pops up a custom dialog containing a the DatePicker. You could even wire it up correctly to show the selected date as the Text on the Button if you wanted to.