# Style TextView like a Spinner with appcompat v21

Tags: android, textview, android-spinner, android-appcompat, material-design

I want to make a TextView look like a spinner with the new Material style.

I managed to do it with "Widget.Material.Light.Spinner" style, but I didn't find any alternative in AppCompat (v21) resources.
My xml:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/sp_league_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        tools:text="Premier league"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Spinner"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `Spinner` if you need a spinner?

Comment: I need a spinner with custom dialog and this is the easiest way to do it

Comment: Aha, so you're [re-implementing `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170289/show-custom-dialog-when-spinner-is-being-clicked).

Comment: @TWiStErRob they made this stuff absolutely unusable in terms of loader manager lifecycle, so we re-implementing this stuff once again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"
```

But feel free to pick another one: [image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me on pre-Lollipop. Will now publish how I've done it.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I tested on 4.4, but looking at the date this may have been before the overhauled appcompat-v7 for Lollipop.

Comment: Makes sense. Sorry. if you find a better solution than what I did, please update and notify about it.

Comment: Doing this in AndroidX gives the TextView a dropdown arrow.

Answer (score 1):

The style solution didn't work for me, but I've found another solution:

I use AppCompatButton instead, and have this :

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
 android:background="@drawable/abc_spinner_mtrl_am_alpha"
 ... />
```

Java:

```
((AppCompatButton)findViewById(...)).setSupportBackgroundTintList(new ColorStateList(new int[][]{new int[0]}, new int[]{0xff52A1E8}));
```

---

EDIT: seems it won't work well anymore, but found another solution :

```
<style name="Widget.MyTheme.HeaderBar.Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
</style>
```

It's true that it's for the action bar , but it should work for other cases too.

Comment: This method worked well for pre-lollipop devices. However, it didn't look good on lollipop because there was box drawn in the background. I had to use `TextView` with `style="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner"` on API 21 or later. I used AppCompat v23.0.1.

Comment: @hfann Hmmm... this was a long time ago, and it used to work. Will now add what's working for me.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I tried your latest sol. of using `Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar` and yes I tried on non-actionbar item. But on 4.1 device, it is not working, meaning does not show a drop-down spinner UI but only displays Plain TextView.

Comment: @androiddeveloper No, It does not on device running pre-lollipop. Hence, I developed another solution and posted below: Just in case if anyone trying to use it for pre-lollipop devices.

Comment: @AADTechnical I've tested it on an emulator of API 10 (GB), and it works (shows a small white triangle next to the text). Maybe you should change the background of the view that contains the TextView .

Comment: @androiddeveloper OK, I will try your above trick to see if it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I Tested the the solutions mentioned here 
 1.Using `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner`) and 
2.Using `Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar`

Both these works only on Android 5.x And Above Devices and **do not** work well for Android devices running on 4.x and below.

Hence, I am posting my solution for those who wanted to have a Drop-down like effect to `TextView` for all devices.

App needs to create a `Drawable` inside `drawable` folder in App, let's say `dropdown_spinner.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_icon_arrow"
    android:gravity="end" />
```

And then simply use this as a background for the TextView as below:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/mySpinnerTextView"
     android:background="@drawable/dropdown_spinner"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

Answer (score 0):

In AndroidX, use `style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"`